# Why sending postman GET request slower than accessing the same endpoint in browser?

Tags: laravel, postman

Basically the title. With postman, sending an API get response takes about 32 seconds, however, sending the same request using a browser with debugbar is way much faster which takes only 3 seconds. Can you please enlighten me I might be doing something wrong here?

Comment: What the the size of the request body and response body?

Comment: Response body is 131.75KB. I'm not sure where I can find the request body size as I'm trying to fetch all the profiles in a paginated way. This is in local by the way while the database is hosted in AWS.

Comment: Usually postman is slow with large requests or responses. Try using insomnia

Comment: Couple of things to check **(1)** Are you using the latest version? As of writing this [7.21.2](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) is the latest Postman version. **(2)** What is the actual response time shown for the request? Check `Time:` value next to status. Or check the [Postman Console](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/debugging-and-logs/). **(3)** Finally, do you have any tests/script setup in Postman for this request?

Comment: Pardon my stupidity. I was sending a view along with the data when accessing the endpoint through browser so I can use debugbar and sending a resource collection when using postman. Apparently, sending a resource collection is really slow.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have the opposite problem.  Chrome takes about 700ms to get a response from an API while in postman the same request takes 100ms.